# Using .htaccess, how can i change file extension at run time

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make a website with PHP, but don't want to show the extension like `http://example.com/index.php`, i have that `index.php` file but want to show only `index.html`, may be `.html` something else..

I don't know how to do, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on  

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/file.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=301,L]

# To internally rewrite /dir/file.html to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: What does external and internal redirect means?

Comment: `external redirect` sends `302/301` status to browser and browser changes URL in address bar. `Internal rewrite` happens only in Apache and browser doesn't see that happening.

Comment: Should i use both at the same time?

Comment: Yes you do need both to serve different purposes. See my comments above both rules.

Answer (score 2):

There is a really easy way with .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [R=301,L]
```